# Extentreport log lines are being repeated

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

I am using extent reports to generate logs for my selenium tests with Page object model and I have separate classes for pages & tests. I am able to generate extent report logs but my login page logs are being repeated. I doubt this is because the login is being used in all other tests but I am unable to resolve this, as I am new to Java. Please help.

Extent reports class

```
package util;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class Reports {

        public static ExtentReports extent;
        public static ExtentTest test;

    public static ExtentReports getInstance() {
        if(extent == null) {
            GetExtent();
        }
        return extent;
    }
    public static ExtentReports GetExtent() {

        /*Create ExtentReports object passing location and report name as argument. Notice a new Result Log folder will be created inside project and the report name will be TestReport.html*/
        extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/RESULT_LOG" + "/TestReport.html", true);
        // Add details to our report
        extent.addSystemInfo("Selenium Version", "3.0.1").addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
        return extent;
    }
    // Start Test Case
    public void startTest (String testCaseName, String description) {
            // Create ExtentTest passing test case name and description
            test = extent.startTest(testCaseName, description);

        }
        // Log Test status, Test name and Test details
        public void logStatus (LogStatus testStatus, String testStepName, String testDetails){

        // Log test status
        test.log(testStatus, testStepName, testDetails);
    }

        // Capture screenshot and log into report
        public void screenshotLog (LogStatus logStatus, String testStepName, String screenShotPath){

        // Attach screenshots
        test.log(logStatus, testStepName + test.addScreenCapture(screenShotPath));
    }

        // End Test Case
        public void endTest() {
            // End test
            extent.endTest(test);
            extent.flush();
        }

        public void endReport(){
            extent.close();
        }


}
```

Login Page class

```
package pages;

import base.TestBase;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import util.Reports;


public class LoginPage extends TestBase {
    Reports reports;

    //Page Factories

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='email']")
    WebElement username;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='pwd']")
    WebElement password;

    @FindBy(xpath="//fieldset[@id='submitButton']")
    WebElement loginBtn;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@title='guest']")
    WebElement guestTab;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@title='grid']")
    WebElement gridViewTab;

    //Initializing the page objects

    public LoginPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        reports = new Reports();
    }

    //Actions

    public String validateLoginPageTitle() {
        String ActualTitle =driver.getTitle();
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Get the title", "Title is fetched" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");
        return ActualTitle;
    }

    public FloorView login(String un, String pw) throws InterruptedException {
        username.sendKeys(un);
        // Extent Report Logging. Enter Log status for HTML report
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Enter user name", "User name entered" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");
        password.sendKeys(pw);
        // Extent Report Logging. Enter Log status for HTML report
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Enter password", "Password entered" + " <span class='label success'>Success</span>");
        loginBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        // Extent Report Logging. Enter Log status for HTML report
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Click Login", "Login button clicked" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");
        return new FloorView();
    }


    public GuestPage navigateToGuests(){
        guestTab.click();
         return new GuestPage();
    }
    public GridView navigateToGridView(){
        gridViewTab.click();
            return new GridView();
    }


}
```

Login Page Test

```
package testcases;

import base.TestBase;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import pages.FloorView;
import pages.LoginPage;
import util.Reports;


public class LoginPageTest extends TestBase {

    LoginPage loginPage;
    FloorView floorView;
    Reports reports;
    static ExtentReports extent;

    public LoginPageTest() {
        super();

    }
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setupReport(){
        extent = Reports.getInstance();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        initialization();
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        reports = new Reports();
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void LoginPageTitleTest(){
        // Start Extent Report
        reports.startTest("Login Page Title Test","Launch application and verify that the correct web page is opened");
        String title = loginPage.validateLoginPageTitle();
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(title, "Eat App Restaurant");
            reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS, "Validate Page title", "Page title Validated" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            reports.logStatus(LogStatus.FAIL, "Validate Page title", "Wrong title, test failed" + " <span class='fail label'>Fail</span>");
        }
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void LoginTest() throws InterruptedException {
        // Start Extent Report
        reports.startTest("Login Test","Navigate to Application, verify Login page is opened. Login to the application and verify that login is successful, and floor view is opened by default.");
        floorView = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
        String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
          if(currentURL.equals("https://cactus-staging.netlify.com/floor")) {
              reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS, "Verify login is successful", "Logged in, Floor View opened" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>"); }
            else{
                reports.logStatus(LogStatus.FAIL, "Verify login is successful", "Login failed" + " <span class='fail label'>Fail</span>");
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        reports.endTest();
        driver.quit();

    }

     @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite(){
        reports.endReport();
    }

    }
```

Grid view page

```
package pages;

import base.TestBase;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import util.Reports;

import java.util.List;

public class GridView extends TestBase {
    Reports reports;

    //Page factories
    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='pages-styles--addButton-9Gd']/span[2]")
    List<WebElement> bookingSlots;

    @FindBy(xpath="//ol[@class='shared-components-walkin-styles--list-3JB']/li")
    List<WebElement> partySize;

    @FindBy(xpath="//button[contains(text(),'Finish Reservation')]")
    WebElement finishReservationBtn;

    public GridView() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        reports = new Reports();
    }
    AddBookingView addBookingView = new AddBookingView();


    public void reserveFromGridView(String pax, String slot, String table) throws InterruptedException {

        //Choose Party size

        for (WebElement li : partySize) {
            if (li.getText().equals(pax)) {
                li.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Select covers", "Covers selected" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");

       //Choose booking time slot
        for (WebElement li : bookingSlots) {
            if (li.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(slot)) {
                li.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Select booking slot", "Booking slot selected" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");


        //Choose Table
        addBookingView.chooseTable(table);
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Select table", "Table selected" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");


        //Finish reservation
        finishReservationBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Click Finish", "Clicked on Finish" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");

    }
}
```

Grid view test class

```
package testcases;

import base.TestBase;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import pages.FloorView;
import pages.GridView;
import pages.LoginPage;
import util.Reports;
import util.TestUtil;

public class GridViewTest extends TestBase {

    LoginPage loginPage;
    FloorView floorView;
    GridView gridView;
    String sheetName = "gridview";
    Reports reports;

    @BeforeMethod
    //Browser set up and log in to the application
    public void setUp() throws InterruptedException{
        initialization();
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        reports = new Reports();
        floorView = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] CactusTestData(){
        Object data[][] = TestUtil.getTestData(sheetName);
        return data;
    }

    @Test(priority=14, dataProvider="CactusTestData")
    public void reserveFromGridViewTest(String pax, String bookingTime, String table) throws InterruptedException {
        // Start Extent Report
        reports.startTest("Grid View Test","Launch the application and make a reservation from Grid view");

        gridView = loginPage.navigateToGridView();
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.INFO, "Navigate to Grid View", "Opened grid view" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");

        gridView.reserveFromGridView(pax,bookingTime,table);
        reports.logStatus(LogStatus.PASS, "Finish reservation", "Reservation is made" + " <span class='label success'> Success</span>");

           }

    //Quit browser
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        reports.endTest();
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

So, the report is being generated like this. The login page test has repeated lines of the logs.[Click to view the report generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7aJW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because two of your test classes has this login method invoked.
Login Page Test class - 
floorView = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));

Grid view test class - @BeforeMethod
floorView = loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));

If you are trying to run these tests independently, then you have start separate extent test nodes on the seperate Extent report.